# Render ExtJs Line chart Square markers

Tags: extjs, charts, markers, lineseries

I am trying to render ExtJS Line chart markers as square but the shape is always circle. Below is my code :

```
  renderer: function (sprite, record, attr, index, {
                    return Ext.apply(attr, {
                        type: 'square',
                         size: 4,
                        fill: '#FFF'

                    });
                }
```

I have sample implementation here : https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/nq4

Please help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `markerConfig` to adjust the marker attributes.

```
markerConfig: {
   type: 'square',
   height:10,
   width:10,
   'fill': '#fff'
}
```

Here is a [fiddle demonstrating](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/nsq)

Comment: Thanks @weeksdev . But I want different shape markers for the same line series.  I can do it via renderer, by putting just an if condition inside it. But it is not possible with markerConfig, as it sets same shape to all markers of a series. Apologies that I didn't made it clear earlier, but can you help me implement different shaped markers for same series ?